# Creating localhost and running jquery application

Tags: jquery, localhost

I have created a simple jquery application, where I want to load all the images from the folder in local machine. I am making a ajax call to load all the images. I have written some code inside the $(document).ready function but while running the code I am getting below error in my console.

I have created a simple package.json file and started a local server running the command http-server o.-o
It started in  http://127.0.0.1:8080 but I can not see my page.

```
$.ajax({
        url : "image/frames",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log($(data));
        }
    });
```

I am getting below Error :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///H:/Frame/image/frames' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: If you are running it on `http://127.0.0.1:8080` you need to access your page from that address so it can execute ajax requests to the same domain.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/index it is working now but I am not able to access the local folder.